# Fly to cart effect - generic image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, effect

Tried searching everywhere but couldn't find a solution, so here goes.

Based on the following script - http://codepen.io/ElmahdiMahmoud/pen/tEeDn

Rather than have an image that has rendered on the page to fly to the basket, how can I override this with a generic image say this for example: http://lorempixel.com/400/200/ ---- the path I will use will be to an images folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the product image to a custom one, then you can do it by changing 
your code from this:

```
var imgclone = imgtodrag.clone()
                        .offset({
                            top: imgtodrag.offset().top,
                            left: imgtodrag.offset().left
                        }) // ...
```

to:

```
// The image that flies to the cart.
var $img_to_move = $('<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />');

// use that image
var imgclone = $img_to_move.offset({
    top:  imgtodrag.offset().top,
    left: imgtodrag.offset().left
}) // ...
```

Check here for the working example: [click](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cKGko)

And offcourse change the name of the `imgClone` variable so that it matches what it does or even remove it and just use the `$img_to_move` further in your code. Didn't changed it for clearance.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the best solution for jQuery fly to cart effect from here - [Fly to cart effect using jQuery](http://www.codexworld.com/fly-to-cart-effect-using-jquery/)
Uses of this script is very simple like the below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.add-to-cart').on('click',function(){
       //Scroll to top if cart icon is hidden on top
       $('html, body').animate({
          'scrollTop' : $(".cart_anchor").position().top
       });
       //Select item image and pass to the function
       var itemImg = $(this).parent().find('img').eq(0);
       flyToElement($(itemImg), $('.cart_anchor'));
   });
});
```